# How similar do two web services need to be for the endpoint addresses to be interchangeable without updating the service reference?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service

I have built and deployed a web service onto a server – let’s call this WebService1. The web service has a number of utility methods which can retrieve, update, remove entries from a database.

I want to create another web service with different but similar functionality to WebService1. Let’s call this WebService2. It will also have the ability to retrieve, update, remove entries from a database, but the code inside the methods of WebService2 will be fundamentally different to WebService1, and WebService2 will be accessing a separate database to the database of WebService1.

If I set up a Service Reference using the endpoint address of WebService1 inside a C# Project, in theory should it be possible to only change the endpoint address to instead point to WebService2 without needing to update the Service Reference and still be able to call methods from the Web Service?

Obviously if I build and deploy WebService1 onto two different servers, it’s very simple to just change the endpoint address between the two services since they are using the exact same codebase, but should it be possible to do something similar by deploying WebService1 and WebService2 to two different servers if the two services have different code bases, provided the public facing web methods have the same method names with the same argument types and names and same return types? If this is possible, is there a fundamental difference between the two web services that would need the service reference to be updated as well as changing the endpoint address when changing between the two?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using soap web services. soap technology uses XML serialization in order to send and receive and XML serialization depends on lots of thing like: class namespace, parameters type, ....
for instance if you are using different namespaces in the inputs you wouldn't be able to switch the address.
but i thinkyou are doing it wrong. if you use restful web services with json input you can easily switch between endpoints.
restful web services is more flexible than soap.